# When to use countByValue and when to use map().reduceByKey()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, word-count

I am new to Spark and scala and working on a simple wordCount example.

So for that i am using countByValue as follows:

```
val words = lines.flatMap(x => x.split("\\W+")).map(x => x.toLowerCase())
val wordCount = words.countByValue();
```

which works fine.

And the same thing can be achieved like :

```
val words = lines.flatMap(x => x.split("\\W+")).map(x => x.toLowerCase())
val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)
val sortedWords = wordCounts.map(x => (x._2, x._1)).sortByKey()
```

which also works fine.

Now, my question is when to use which methods?
Which one is preferred over the other?

Comment: Would you consider the answer meeting your request for knowledge?

Comment: In the statement: val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)   Could someone explain why x + y ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example here - not words, but numbers:

```
val n = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,4,2,1,1,1,1,1))
val n2 = n.countByValue
```

returns a local Map:

```
n: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[4] at parallelize at command-3737881976236428:1
n2: scala.collection.Map[Int,Long] = Map(5 -> 1, 1 -> 6, 6 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 7 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 8 -> 1, 4 -> 2)
```

That is the key difference.

If you want a Map out of the box, then this is the way to go.

Also, the point is that the reduce is implied and cannot be influenced, nor need be provided as in reduceByKey.

The reduceByKey has preference when data sizes are large. The Map is loaded into Driver memory in its entirety.

Answer (score 10):

At least in PySpark, they are different things.

`countByKey` is implemented with `reduce`, which means that the driver will collect the partial results of the partitions and does the merge itself. If your result is large, then the driver will have to merge a large number of large dictionaries, which will make the driver crazy.

`reduceByKey` shuffles the keys to different executors and does the reduction in every worker, so it is more favorable if the data is large.

In conclusion, when your data is large, use `map`, `reduceByKey` and `collect` will make your driver much happier. If your data is small, `countByKey` will introduce less network traffic (one less stage).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  I have two doubts 
1, assume there is a very large dataset terabyte size, and you are doing count by key. So the value part is only the count . Normally driver goes out of memory when the value part is bigger, key size rarely creates a problem. 
2, When you say countByKey is implemented with reduce, does it mean any such function will get the results from each partition( only map) and the reduce part will happen in the driver ?

Answer (score 7):

Adding to all the above answers, here is what i found further:

1. CountByValue return a map which can not be used in distributed manner.
2. ReduceByKey returns an rdd which can be further used in a distributed manner.

Answer (score 1):

1. countByValue() is an RDD action that returns the count of each unique
   value in this RDD as a dictionary of (value, count) pairs.
2. reduceByKey() is an RDD transformation that returns an RDD in format of  pairs